# Failed to transform react-native-reanimated-65-jsc.aar

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

```
BUILD FAILED in 19s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform react-native-reanimated-65-jsc.aar (project :react-native-reanimated) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata}.       
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\Rahul\Desktop\lcorn\rb\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\react-native-reanimated-65-jsc.aar.         > Transform's input file does not exist: C:\Users\Rahul\Desktop\lcorn\rb\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\react-native-reanimated-65-jsc.aar. (See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158753935)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s

    at makeError (C:\Users\Rahul\Desktop\lcorn\rb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\Rahul\Desktop\lcorn\rb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\Rahul\Desktop\lcorn\rb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:106:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\Rahul\Desktop\lcorn\rb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
PS C:\Users\Rahul\Desktop\lcorn\rb> 


"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.65.0",
```

Comment: I had this same problem with react 17.0.2, react-native 0.65.1, and react-native-reanimated 2.2.0. Yarn uninstall and yarn install did not work. Yarn uninstall and npm install did work. (as of late september 2021 and not specifying version when running these commands).

Comment: just do one thing only tun command-- npm uninstall react-native-reanimated

Answer (score 29):

I don't think react-native-reanimated supports Hermes on Android with React Native 0.65.0. I was able to fix it removing react-native-reanimated because I don't use it. Maybe you can remove it or disable Hermes.

Installing react-native-reanimated@2.3.0-alpha.2 also fixes it.

Comment: fixed by installing react-native-reanimated@2.2.0

Answer (score 14):

This issue has been fixed in the latest build (alpha release).

```
yarn add react-native-reanimated@2.3.0-alpha.3
```

Here is the list of version releases: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-reanimated?activeTab=versions

Answer (score 8):

New upgrade is not yet released react-native-reanimated-65-jsc.aar.

After the installation of the package, navigate to node_modules folder and search for react-native-reanimated. Navigate to android and see if anything ending with 65 is visible.. else it wont work.

[image]

Alternate options, [with downgrade to 0.64.2] it does work... but the version gets reset after the build.

This is one of the key file to be updated ***node_modules> react-native-reanimated > android > build.gradle*** to make it work

Follow the instructions as given in the site

> https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/installation/

set the following too **enableHermes: true** .. No harm in setting it

Now follow these steps

1. in your android > gradle > wrapper>gradle-wrapper.properties change
   ***distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8-all.zip***
2. android > build. gradle. Change these two items; as class path goes set with 6.8-all goes with 4.2.2

[image]

3. uninstall react-native .65 and run for 0.64.2
4. delete your package-lock.json
5. watchman watch-del-all
6. Delete node_modules
7. run yarn install
8. yarn start --reset-cache
9. rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
10. [This can be an optional step..as RN .64 is set]

Now go back to the node_modules folder and search for the 'react-native-reanimated' folder and change this

**artifacts.add("default", file("react-native-reanimated-${minor}.aar"))**

to

**artifacts.add("default", file("react-native-reanimated-64.aar"))**

Now start with your build.. you should not see the issue reported.

. Update

Comment: This solution works for me. The only difference is I had to use "artifacts.add("default", file("react-native-reanimated-64-hermes.aar"))" instead of "artifacts.add("default", file("react-native-reanimated-64.aar"))" because when I checked node_modules/react-native-reanimated folder there are only react-native-reanimated-64-jsc.aar and react-native-reanimated-64-hermes.aar files. I'm using react-native-reanimated 2.2.0

Answer (score 3):

Just install react-native-reanimated@2.3.0-alpha.3 or any updated version.
It will fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have upgraded my react native vers to 0.65.1 and had this problem too. Try to make:

1. npm uninstall react-native-reanimated
2. npm i react-native-reanimated
3. cd android
4. ./gradlew wrapper
5. cd ..
6. npx react-native run-android

Answer (score -3):

If you don't want to use alpha version of the library, you may install `react-native-reanimated@2.2.1` too for React Native `0.65`